# inherit terraform .tf file from a parent directory

Tags: terraform

terraform==0.12.28

The goal is to inherit a terraform .tf file from an upstream directory.  I've been following this [repo](https://github.com/morgante/deployment-example/blob/master/deployments/networking/dev/variables.tf) that shows that it's possible by just stating the relative upstream file path within a .tf file. Although when I run

1. `terraform init` only within the cwd
2. `terraform init` within the parent directory and then the cwd

Both attempts output the error:

```
Error: Argument or block definition required

on shared_data.tf line 1:
   1: ../../shared_data.tf
```

To combat this error I've tried using a terraform variable to define the relative path first:

```
variable "shared_data_path" {
    default = "../../shared_data.tf"
}
var.shared_data_path
```

Which outputs the error:

```
Error: Argument or block definition required

  on shared_data.tf line 4:
  4: var.shared_data_path

An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That repo that you are looking at does not inherit the data by just writing the name of the file like you are doing. The file that you have linked to is a symlink, which means that Terraform sees that file as having the actual content of the file in the parent directory. You can see this in the header of the file, and if you had cloned that repository, you would see that it is a symlink when you look at it on your computer.

Assuming you have this sort of directory tree:

```
- parent_dir/
  |-shared_data.tf
  |-child_dir/
    |-something.tf
```

then you can create a symlink in `child_dir` by `cd`ing into  `child_dir` in your terminal, then running `ln -s ../shared_data.tf .`

Then you will have a tree like

```
- parent_dir/
  |-shared_data.tf
  |-child_dir/
    |-something.tf
    |-shared_data.tf -> ../shared_data.tf
```